# what is the integral of the form $\int f(dx)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, integration, measure-theory

there is some kinds of form of integral that showed in the book about the empirical process(Introduction of Empirical Processes and Semiparametric Inference)that I don't understand, and here is the integral:

$\int (\sqrt{n}(d(P_n)^{1/2}-d(P)^{1/2})-(1/2)h*d(P)^{1/2})^2$

where $P_n$ and $P$ are the measures,so my question is what is the meaning of 
$\int f(dx)$?

For example what is
$\int (dx)^2$? How to compute it?

Comment: Maybe in that example, integral of $dx^2=\int (dx)dx=xdx$. In regular integration you scale an infinitesimal by dx. I think,??? in the same way something like cos(dx) or in general f(dx), f changes the "size" of infinitesimal you integrate/sum. Don't quote me on this, but just a pointer maybe on what it appears to mean intuitively at first glance. I'm not sure if that's legit though.

Comment: Wait, I thought dx was something that just goes along with integrals. Can dx go inside a function?